# std::vector that can be consumed fast

Tags: c++

I'd like to be able to consume parts of a buffer until it's empty. I designed my own below, but I'd like to know if there is such thing in the std library already, so I remove the possibilities of implementing my own wrong.

Note that I use `std::vector<T>` only for automatic storage. I don't do `push_back` to insert and `pop_back` to consume because I want the consumption of data to be as fast as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    class Buffer
    {
    public:
        void write(T* buffer, size_t amountToWrite) {
            if (amountToWrite <= this->_buffer.capacity()) {
                std::copy(buffer, buffer + amountToWrite, this->_buffer.data());
                _size += amountToWrite;
            } else {
                //In fact I wanted to increase capacity, not size. However we don't use the vector functions, so does it mater?
                this->_buffer.resize(amountToWrite);
                std::copy(buffer, buffer + amountToWrite, this->_buffer.data());
                _size += amountToWrite;
            }
        }
    
        size_t consume(T* bufferToWrite, size_t amountToConsume) {
            if (_current==_size) {
               //this means we've already read everything. Maybe we should throw or just return 0?
               return 0; 
            }
            if (amountToConsume <= this->_size) {
                std::copy(this->_buffer.data() + _current, this->_buffer.data() + _current + amountToConsume, bufferToWrite);
                _current += amountToConsume;
                return amountToConsume;
            } else {
                size_t remaining = this->_size - amountToConsume;
                std::copy(this->_buffer.data() + _current, this->_buffer.data() + _current + remaining, bufferToWrite);
                _current += remaining;
                return remaining;
            }
        }
    
    private:
        size_t _size = 0;
        std::vector<T> _buffer;
        size_t _current = 0;
    };

int main()
{
    Buffer<uint8_t> b;
    uint8_t u[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    b.write(u, 6);

    uint8_t r[3];
    size_t consumedBytes = b.consume(r, 3);
    std::cout << "consumed " << consumedBytes << std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        std::cout << (int) r[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    size_t consumedBytes2 = b.consume(r, 3);
    std::cout << "consumed " << consumedBytes2 << std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        std::cout << (int) r[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    size_t consumedBytes3 = b.consume(r, 3);
    std::cout << "consumed " << consumedBytes3 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Do you see anything wrong in my implementation?

I'm trying to do the safest possible thing while making it fast.

Comment: While `push_back` *can* cause a reallocation (unless the capacity is enough) `pop_back` will not change the capacity and is essentially as quick as normal "array" access.

Comment: This serves no purpose. Using a plain `std::vector` with `reserve` and `insert` will be at least as fast, if not faster. Also copying the end portion of a vector and then resizing in down is again at least as fast, if not faster.

Comment: I think the test `amountToWrite <= this->_buffer.capacity()` is suspect. I believe writing more than `size()` elements would put you in undefined behavior territory.

Comment: *"Do you see anything wrong in my implementation?"* -- Stack Overflow is not the place for open-ended code review.

Comment: @super why reserve? Doesn't `insert` reallocate?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what I actually need is pop_front though

Comment: It reallocates if there isn't enough capacity to hold the inserted elements. If you have reserved enough there's no reallocation (insert would only increase the size).

Comment: @Blastfurnace so I don't see why I would ever need it in my example

Comment: You do understand the difference between `size()` and `capacity()`? My concern with your code is that you may try to add more elements than the current `size()`. That's undefined behavior, you can't just check `capacity()` and write past the current `_buffer.end()`

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes, technically the implementation of std::vector can do whatever it wants with the data past size() because in theory it's not being used. I confused what you said with the other person

Comment: I was responding to your question asking "why reserve?". Doing a reserve before a bunch of `push_back()` or `insert()` calls can reduce memory allocations caused by vector growth and, therefore, run faster.

Comment: @Gatonito You use reserve to avoid reallocation when using a vector. It's basically meant for this kind of use case, you get the benefit of keeping the whole `std::vector` interface but can make sure you don't do uneccesary reallocations to optimize performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take advantage of using dequeue from STL.
It implements a doubly linkedlist in which you can read from one side and write from the other side of it. Check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deque-cpp-stl/) for more detail explanations.

Also the other best implementation for a buffer is a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) implementation.

I leave a C++ implementation code for a circular buffer.

```
class MyCircularQueue {
vector<int> mem;
int front;
int rear;
int len;
int cnt;

public:
MyCircularQueue(int k) {
   len = k;
   mem = vector<int> (k); 
   front = 0;
   rear = -1;
   cnt=0; 
}

bool enQueue(int value) {
    if(isFull())
        return false;

    rear = (rear+1) %len;
    mem[rear]= value;
    cnt++;
    return true;
}

bool deQueue() {
    if (isEmpty()) 
        return  false;
    front = (front+1) % len;
    cnt--;
    return true;
}

int Front() {
    if (isEmpty()) 
        return -1;
    return mem[front];
}

int Rear() {
    if (isEmpty()) 
       return -1;
    return mem[rear];
}

bool isEmpty() {
   return (cnt ==0); 
}

bool isFull() {
    return ( cnt == len);
}
```

};